# Conditional formatting for different column with different criteria in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have a table with grades for different subjects and would like to apply conditional formatting based on specific criteria for each column (subject) using cell references. This way, I can easily change the conditions in the table instead of manually modifying formulas. Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

```markdown
| Subject | Red  | Yellow    | Green |
|---------|------|-----------|-------|
| Maths   | =0   | 0 < Marks < 35  | >=35  |
| English | =0   | 0 < Marks < 25  | >=25  |
| History | =0   | 0 < Marks < 40  | >=40  |
```

```markdown
|   name | Maths | English | History |
|--------|-------|---------|---------|
|    San |    70 |      39 |      45 |
|  Swati |    50 |      59 |      49 |
|  Shara |    65 |      24 |      47 |
```

I want the values in the "Maths", "English", and "History" columns to be formatted based on their values relative to the criteria in the corresponding row in the first table. For example, if a student scored less than 35 in Maths, I want the cell to be red, between 35 and 0 to be yellow, and 35 or greater to be green. How can I apply these conditional formats to the cells in my table based on these criteria?

Comment: Why don't you just put the lower limit of each band of marks in the first table? -  e.g. for Maths it would be 0, 1 and 35 if I understand correctly - then you can use a lookup on subject and another one on mark band.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion if you are able to use Xlookup:

[image]

You need three separate formulas like

```
=XLOOKUP(B8,XLOOKUP(B$7,$A$2:$A$4,$B$2:$D$4),$B$1:$D$1,,-1)="Red"
```